# Fixing JPopupMenu separators (GTK LaF) and items highlighting

Tags: java, swing, popup

yesterday I've been using for the first time Swing for a quick desktop application (I'm a fan of swt indeed...).

BTW I came across a couple of problems with JPopupMenu:

1) With GTK LaF, separators are not showing [due to a bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=613134).

2) While moving the mouse over menu items, they do not highlight (seen on linux and win)

Comment: So there's no question, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I just wanted to share a solution since sometimes you spend hours for "cosmetic" problems while you want to focus on the core of your application... :)

Comment: Consider using [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to extend JPopupMenu class in order to fix the two issues above and now I just want to share the code, just in case someone faces the same problem.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class JPopupMenuEx
extends JPopupMenu
implements MouseListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5352058505305990803L;

    @Override
    public void addSeparator() {
        add(new JSeparatorEx());
    }

    @Override
    public JMenuItem add(JMenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.addMouseListener(this);
        return super.add(menuItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        ((JMenuItem)e.getSource()).setArmed(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        ((JMenuItem)e.getSource()).setArmed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public class JSeparatorEx extends JSeparator{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3477309905456341629L;

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

            if (d.height==0)
                d.height = 4;

            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it just like using JPopupMenu, like this:

```
JPopupMenuEx popup = new JPopupMenuEx();
popup.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Item 1"));
popup.addSeparator();
popup.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));
```

Comment: @trashgod this is one of SilentHappyMode, since I'm follower of RouwdiesHappyMode this sefl-answer is really, so good, very nice :-)

Comment: @mKorbel: Ah, I forgot; you use Java with `GTKLookAndFeel`.

Comment: @trashgod, I pulled the answer out of the question to fit the standard Stack Overflow style. lviggiani, don't forget that you can accept your own answer by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation using [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), as well as an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for future reference.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254488 */
public class JPopupMenuEx extends JPopupMenu {

    private MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JMenuItem) e.getSource()).setArmed(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JMenuItem) e.getSource()).setArmed(false);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void addSeparator() {
        add(new JSeparatorEx());
    }

    @Override
    public JMenuItem add(JMenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        return super.add(menuItem);
    }

    private static class JSeparatorEx extends JSeparator {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
            if (d.height == 0) {
                d.height = 4;
            }
            return d;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPopupMenuEx popup = new JPopupMenuEx();
                popup.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Item 1"));
                popup.addSeparator();
                popup.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.add(new JLabel("Right click for context menu."));
                p.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
                f.add(p);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: always with SSCCE, how long I din't see JSeparator, thanks for example +1